# List element appears more than 2 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have NumPy

```
from collections import Counter
import NumPy as np
a = [ 'abc', 'abc','bca','fdf','dfd','abc','bca','bca']
```

I used

```
if Counter (a) > 2:
  print (a)

Type Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'Counter' and 'int'
```

I want the output is list of element appear more than 2 times in the dataset.

Comment: You have a list, not any `numpy` array.

Comment: And what would your *expected outcome* be? Just a true or false result, or do you have to have the elements that appear more than twice too?

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of element appear more than 2 times in the dataset.

```
[x for x,y in Counter(a).items() if y > 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the highest count in the counter is greater than 2; you can use [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to extract the highest count:

```
if Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][1] > 2:
```

`Counter.most_common()` returns a list of `(value, count)` pairs, even when you ask for just a single pair; `[0]` gets that one `(value, count)` pair from the list, and `[1]` extracts the count.